# Can you share a folder of DLLs between different programs? C++ VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, runtime

I have a bunch of programs in a directory structure like this:

C: \PARENT \PROGRAMS \Program1

C: \PARENT \PROGRAMS \Program2 ...

and a bunch of DLLs required by all of the programs. 
Is there any way to share them (i.e. not have a copy of each DLL in each program's folder)?

Ideally the DLLs can go in a folder here:

C: \PARENT \SHARED \DLLS

I have previously used the PATH environment variable and manually added the folder, but this is NO longer an option.

I've tried adding the path to the DLLs (in VS2010)  in the project settings, but as soon as the program is run outside of VS then I get the error box "Your dll cannot be found..."

Comment: Are the dlls that you're using in the same folder as your .exe?

Comment: @stazima That's the problem. In order for the .exe to run the .dlls need to be next to it, but I want to change that to prevent having multiple copies of the .dlls  (a copy in each of the Programs folders)

Comment: There's `AddDllDirectory`. You'll need configure delay-load for those DLLs so that you have a chance to actually call the function before loading them. Alternatively, you should be able to specify the search path in the [application manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191.aspx), but I'm not familiar with the details.

Comment: As igor said you could use that method which would require that the paths to the dlls never change. This is usually OK for system dlls that you know will be installed on all systems. If they're custom dlls or libraries that you've downloaded then the most surefire way to have it cross-system compatible is to just include it in the same directory as the .exe